# Unity dropdown not refreshing properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am making a dropdown for my resolution-settings. I populate it programatically and after I am done I refresh it so that the scrollbar will start at the currently selected value.

However that is not working, the scrollbar always starts at the top, even though the selected value is at the bottom.

Code:

```
    public TMP_Dropdown resolutionDd;
    //...
    resolutionDd.AddOptions(options);
    resolutionDd.value = currentResolutionIndex;
    resolutionDd.RefreshShownValue();
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: After `resolutionDd.RefreshShownValue();` the curent selected item and the list should be updated. However, afaik the List **allways** starts at the top not at the currently selected item...

Comment: @derHugo I think you are right. Kind of sucks but not a huge deal, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you use firebase to this, (my case) use external calls, example:

```
fs.Collection("app").GetSnapshotAsync().ContinueWith(it => 
    {
        if (it.IsCompleted)
        {
            if (it.Result.Count > 0)
            {
                documents = it.Result;               
            }
        }
    });

    
private void Update()
{

    if (documents != null)
    {
        //actualize here all data
        resolutionDd.RefreshShownValue();
        documents = null;
    }
}
```